# Repeatedly being in combat in Frostgrave

Tags: frostgrave

My friends and I recently tried out Frostgrave for the first time. As the DM of our DnD group and the person who bought the rulebook I read the rules first, and wanted to run a little "simulation combat" to make them acquainted with the system. Here we encountered the following situation:

1. Player A's turn is up. He decides to run towards a unit of Player B. They come in combat range (1 inch) and initiate combat.
2. Player B's unit wins the roll, and decides to push back A's unit by 1 inch, as B is up next and wants to run towards a treasure token. A still has movement left.

Now, a few questions popped up regarding this situation:

- If A's unit moved towards B's unit again with their leftover movement, they cannot attack again, BUT can they go into combat, locking B's unit in place?
- If A's unit had access to another attack action, could B defend against it? I.e., do they get an opposing Fight roll, and if they win, could they push A's unit back again by 1 inch?
- If A's unit had enough movement after the first attack to move past B's unit (but had to stay inside a 1 inch range of B), could B, who already was in combat this turn, force combat again? Or is his ability to halt an enemy creature depleted for the turn?

I know this is more than one question, technically speaking, but they do arise in the same situation.

Comment: [Wargames are off topic here](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/a/549/62294), but on topic at https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/, so I have flagged this for migration to that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frostgrave's movement cannot be broken up into a "before and after" the way you can do it in D&D. Also, fighting only happens when either character uses one of their actions to fight, not when combat is joined.

So what happens here is:

- A runs towards B, engaging in combat. This ends their move.
- A uses their 2nd action to start a fight. B wins and decides to push them back.

This is two actions, and leftover movement doesn't matter because A's move action ended when they initiated combat. (It would have also ended if they tried to move *past* B, but B decided to initiate combat when they came close enough)

Regarding your other questions:

- if A had a 3rd action and used it to move, they could engage with B again. They can't use leftover movement for this, because that concept doesn't exist in Frostgrave
- yes, B could defend against additional attacks. There is no limit to how often a unit can fight in a round, and yes, they could push away a unit multiple times, or push away multiple units.
- Again, leftover movement isn't a thing, but if A had a 3rd action and moved again, then yes, B could engage in combat once again if A came within 1 inch again. The only requirement for engaging a combat when someone comes nearby is currently being free to move; ie not already in combat.

Comment: Very concise answer, thank you! Apparently I must have read over the rule that movement cannot be broken up, but that solves the issue very elegantly. I'll wait a bit before accepting the answer to give others a chance as well.

Comment: Ah, one followup/clarification please: you say "if A had a 3rd action and used it to move, they could engage with B again" - but, since that little movement to go back in melee range would use up their 3rd action, they could only engage combat, but not actually make an attack/Fight roll?

Comment: Correct. Move is an action; no fight roll happens unless you spend another action on that.